# tensorflow error "raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are not compatible" % (self, other)) ValueError: Shapes (?, 5) and (5,) are not compatible"

Tags: tensorflow

I try to classification of my original records using tensorflow 1.4.0.
The process is as following.

Fist: Read image and labels, and outputting "tfrecord" format into fiiles.
Second: Read tf record and training

write tfrecord script is

```
!/usr/bin/env python3
#coding:utf-8

import argparse
import os
import random

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf

def make_example(label_index, image):
    return tf.train.Example(features = tf.train.Features(feature={
        'label_index': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[label_index])),
        'image': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[image]))
        }))

def write_tfrecord(dataset, outputfilepath):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(outputfilepath)
    for label_of_one_hot, image in dataset:
        ex = make_example(label_of_one_hot, image)
        writer.write(ex.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()

def importingargs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("tensorflow exampe")
    parser.add_argument("--datafolderpath", "-df", help="datafolderpath")
    parser.add_argument("--filepath", "-f", help="filepath", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--labelfilepath", "-lf", help="label filepath")
    parser.add_argument("--outputfolderpath", "-of", help="outputfolderpath of tf records")
    parser.add_argument("--seed", "-s", type=int, required=False, default=0)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args.filepath, args.datafolderpath, args.labelfilepath, args.outputfolderpath, args.seed


def load_data(filepath, datafolderpath, labelfilepath):
    with open(labelfilepath, "r") as rf:
        labellist = [ line.strip() for line in rf.readlines() ]

    with open(filepath,  "r") as rf:
        filepathlist = [ line.strip() for line in rf.readlines() ]


    alldatasets = list()
    for filepath in filepathlist:
        imagefilepath = os.path.join(datafolderpath, filepath)
        # image = open(imagefilepath).read()
        img_obj = Image.open(imagefilepath).convert("L")
        img = np.array(img_obj)
        w, h = img.shape
        print(w, h)
        print(w*h)
        img = img.reshape(w*h).tostring()
        print(type(img))
        filename = filepath.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
        label = filename.split(".")[0].split("_")[1]
        index = labellist.index(label) +1
        print(index)
        alldatasets.append([ index, img ])
    return alldatasets

def splitdata(datasets):
    random.shuffle(datasets)
    train_indexes = [ 0, int(len(datasets) * 0.8 ) ]
    valid_indexes = [ train_indexes[-1], int(len(datasets) * 0.9 ) ]
    test_indexes = [ valid_indexes[-1], int(len(datasets)) ]

    train_data = datasets[train_indexes[0]:train_indexes[1]]
    valid_data = datasets[valid_indexes[0]:valid_indexes[1]]
    test_data = datasets[test_indexes[0]:test_indexes[1]]

    print("train num: %d" % len(train_data))
    print("test  num: %d" % len(test_data))
    print("valid num: %d" % len(valid_data))

    return train_data, valid_data, test_data

def main():
    filepath, datafolderpath, labelfilepath, outputfolderpath, seed = importingargs()
    random.seed(seed)
    alldatasets = load_data(filepath, datafolderpath, labelfilepath)
    train_data, valid_data, test_data = splitdata(alldatasets)
    train_outputfilepath = os.path.join(outputfolderpath, "train.tfrecord")
    valid_outputfilepath = os.path.join(outputfolderpath, "valid.tfrecord")
    test_outptufilepath = os.path.join(outputfolderpath, "test.tfrecord")

    write_tfrecord(train_data, train_outputfilepath)
    write_tfrecord(valid_data, valid_outputfilepath)
    write_tfrecord(test_data, test_outptufilepath)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The load_dataset files importing train.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#coding:utf-8

import argparse
import os

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf

def read_tfrecord(inputfilepath):
    print("read record")
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    filename_que = tf.train.string_input_producer([inputfilepath])
    key, value = reader.read(filename_que)
    features  = tf.parse_single_example(value,features = {
            'label_index': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
            })

    images = tf.decode_raw(features['image'], tf.float32)
    images.set_shape([32*32])
    images = tf.cast(images, tf.float32) * (1. / 255)
    # images = tf.reshape(images, [-1])
    labels = tf.decode_raw(features['label_index'], tf.int32)
    # labels = tf.cast(features['label_index'], tf.int64)
    # labels.set_shape([5])
    print("call one hot")
    label_index_one_hot = tf.one_hot(labels, 5)
    label_index_one_hot.set_shape([5])
    return images, label_index_one_hot
```

Training script is

```
import os
import random

import tensorflow as tf

import load_datasets
import datasets
import make_datasets

print("def input and output")
images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32*32])
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 5])


print("def layers")
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [ None, 32*32 ])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 5 ])

# W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([ 32*32, 500 ]))
# b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([ 500 ]))

# W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([ 500, 5 ]))
# b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([ 5 ]))

print("def function")
# h1 = tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1
# y = tf.matmul(h1, W2) + b2

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([ 32*32, 5 ]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([ 5 ]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

print("def leraning model")
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_,logits=y))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_prediction= tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


print("load train dataset")
trainfilepath = "../03tfrecords/train.tfrecord"
images, labels = load_datasets.read_tfrecord(trainfilepath)
input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer( [images, labels ], num_epochs=10, shuffle=False )
image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch( [images, labels], batch_size=10)

print("load test dataset")
testfilepath = "../03tfrecords/test.tfrecord"
test_image, test_label = load_datasets.read_tfrecord(testfilepath)
img_test_batch, label_test_batch = tf.train.batch([test_image,test_label],batch_size=16)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print("init layer value")
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print("start training")
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    try:
        while not coord.should_stop():
            for i in range(0, 10):
                print("train num %d" % (i+1))
                imgs, labels = sess.run([image_batch, label_batch])
                sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:imgs, y_: labels})

                imgs_test, labels_text = sess.run([img_test_batch, label_test_batch])
                print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x:imgs_test, y_:labels_text}))


    finally:
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

The making tfrecords works well, but in training script, an error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omori/.pyenv/versions/tensorflow-py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 576, in merge_with
    self.assert_same_rank(other)
  File "/home/omori/.pyenv/versions/tensorflow-py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 621, in assert_same_rank
    other))
ValueError: Shapes (?, 5) and (5,) must have the same rank

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 45, in <module>
    images, labels = load_datasets.read_tfrecord(trainfilepath)
  File "/home/omori/tensorflow_example/01src/load_datasets.py", line 30, in read_tfrecord
    label_index_one_hot.set_shape([5])
  File "/home/omori/.pyenv/versions/tensorflow-py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 407, in set_shape
    self._shape = self._shape.merge_with(shape)
  File "/home/omori/.pyenv/versions/tensorflow-py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 582, in merge_with
    raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are not compatible" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (?, 5) and (5,) are not compatible
```

I search the many sites but I can't get the solution.
How can I do solve it?

Answer (score 1):

[decode_raw](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_raw):

```
Returns:

A Tensor of type out_type. A Tensor with one more dimension than the input bytes. The added 
dimension will have size equal to the length of the elements of bytes divided by the number 
of bytes to represent out_type.
```

So in your `read_tfrecord` function the line

```
labels = tf.decode_raw(features['label_index'], tf.int32)
```

gives `labels` an excess dimension.  You can fix this by using

```
label_index_one_hot = tf.one_hot(labels[0], 5)
```

(note the added `[0]`)

I have to admit that I don't understand what the added dimension is for.

Comment: Thanks for your solution!! I tried it, the same error does not occured.
And another problem happend, now it solved and the program woks without errors.However, the accuracy does not converge, maybe something is wrong, and now I tried solve it.