# TensorFlow Error: ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to classify images of PCBs into two categories (`defected` and `undefected`) using `categorical cross-entropy` as the loss function. The code for the same is as below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint


from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def create_compiled_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=RESNET50_WEIGHTS, input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3), pooling=RESNET50_POOLING_AVERAGE))
  model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation=DENSE_LAYER_ACTIVATION))
  model.layers[0].trainable = False

  sgd = SGD(lr = 0.01, decay = 1e-6, momentum = 0.9, nesterov = True)
  model.compile(optimizer = sgd, loss = OBJECTIVE_FUNCTION, metrics = LOSS_METRICS)

  return model

def data_splitor():
  x = np.load("/content/data/xtrain.npy")
  y = np.load("/content/data/ytrain.npy")

  # Getting the Test and Train splits
  x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size= TRAIN_TEST_SPLIT, shuffle= True)

  # Getting the Train and Validation splits
  x__train, x__valid, y__train, y__valid = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size= TRAIN_TEST_SPLIT, shuffle= True)

  return x__train, x__valid, x_test, y__train, y__valid, y_test

def data_generator(x, y, batch_size, seed=None, shuffle=True):
  data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True, rotation_range=180, brightness_range=[0.3, 1.0], preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
  generator = data_generator.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size= batch_size, seed= seed, shuffle=shuffle)
  return generator

def run_program():
  x_train, x_valid, x_test, y_train, y_valid, y_test = data_splitor()
  train_generator = data_generator(x_train, y_train, BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING)
  validation_generator = data_generator(x_valid, y_valid, BATCH_SIZE_VALIDATION)

  cb_early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE)
  cb_checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = '/content/model/best.hdf5', monitor = 'val_loss', save_best_only = True, mode = 'auto')

  model = create_compiled_model()

  fit_history = model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH_TRAINING,
        epochs = NUM_EPOCHS,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=STEPS_PER_EPOCH_VALIDATION,
        callbacks=[cb_checkpointer, cb_early_stopper]
  )

  plt.figure(1, figsize = (15,8)) 

  plt.subplot(221)
  plt.plot(fit_history.history['acc'])  
  plt.plot(fit_history.history['val_acc'])  
  plt.title('model accuracy')  
  plt.ylabel('accuracy')  
  plt.xlabel('epoch')  
  plt.legend(['train', 'valid']) 

  plt.subplot(222)  
  plt.plot(fit_history.history['loss'])  
  plt.plot(fit_history.history['val_loss'])  
  plt.title('model loss')  
  plt.ylabel('loss')  
  plt.xlabel('epoch')  
  plt.legend(['train', 'valid']) 

  plt.show()


  # Testing
  test_generator = data_generator(x_test, y_test, BATCH_SIZE_TESTING, 123, False)
  test_generator.reset()

  model.load_weights("/content/model/best.hdf5")
  pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps = len(test_generator), verbose = 1)

  predicted_class_indices = np.argmax(pred, axis = 1)


# Running the program
try:
  with tensorflow.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    run_program()
except RuntimeError as e:
  print(e)
```

And upon executing this, I get the ValueError seen below:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:533 train_step  **
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:143 __call__
        losses = self.call(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:246 call
        return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1527 categorical_crossentropy
        return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4561 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1117 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible
```

I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49703387/tensorflow-valueerror-shapes-1-and-are-incompatible/50180397), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482082/tensorflow-error-raise-valueerrorshapes-s-and-s-are-not-compatible-self) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406932/tensorflow-label-and-logits-shapes-are-incompatible), but could not resolve the error.

I really appreciate the help in fixing this.

Thanks Praveen

Here is the complete traceback... [link](https://pastebin.com/sKhVXWcp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your y_train data have shape (None,1) while your network is expecting (None,2). There are two options to solve this:

1) Change your model output to 1 unit and change loss to binary crossentropy

or

2) Change your y_train data to categorical. See [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical?version=nightly)

If you can post here your model.summary() and your dataset shapes it will help us to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Changing the y_train into categorical data resolved my error.

Answer (score 1):

Your traceback link isn't working.
However, try replacing categorical cross-entropy with binary cross entropy since you have only two classes.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at the question :) I had tried ```binary cross entropy``` but it did not make any difference.

Comment: @PraveenRaj any fixes you found for this?, please share

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but instead, i was using labels decoded to int64 format from TFRecord files, changing my loss function from 'CategoricalCrossentropy' to 'SparseCategoricalCrossentropy' resolved the issue.

Comment: can you explain why this helps? I did the same for my Petals notebook ... and it worked!

Comment: From Official tensorflow documentation:  ```Use this crossentropy metric when there are two or more label classes. We expect labels to be provided as integers. If you want to provide labels using one-hot representation, please use CategoricalCrossentropy metric. There should be # classes floating point values per feature for y_pred and a single floating point value per feature for y_true. ```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and these above-mentioned solutions did not work. The main reason why we get this error is when we fail to establish the 1 to 1 mapping of data between the X_train and Y_train. This means the shape of Y_train should be in shape like (No_of_Sequnces, no_of_classes).

Example -

Let's say my dataset has 2000  rows and 5 features. where 1 sequence = 100 rows of data.
So before reshaping x_train will look like this

```
X_train.shape = (2000,5)
```

before feeding into LSTM we should reshape it to 3D (usually), hence

```
X_train.reshape(20,100,5)
```

On the other hand, our Y_Train will be initially. (if it is in 2D, change it to 1D by flattening)

```
Y_train.shape = (2000, )
```

So, before feeding into LSTM we should change the Y_train shape like

```
Y_train.shape =(20, 5)
```

the 20 will make the 1:1 mapping with the train set, while the 5 will make the mapping with the final dense layer of the classification model, where we are supposed to use categorical-cross entropy.

Also please note that the Y_train should be in 2D shape. So how do we re-shape it like that?.

1. Check how the _train data are
2. If in string use one-hot representation
3. If integers for each class, convert to categorical ([refer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical?version=nightly))
4. After changing to categorical refer the Y_train again.
5. If the class number and number of column is equal, use the following code to reduce the rows to 20 (lik of X_train)

   ```
   for eachRowTemp in range(df_Y_Labels.__len__()):
      if(eachRowTemp%20 == 1):    
         Y_Label_Array.append(df_Y_Labels.loc[eachRowTemp])
    Y_Label = np.asarray(Y_Label_Array)
   ```

This should work. also you should change the Y_test in similar way.

Answer (score -1):

**Thanks** [**@Augusto maillo**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13392106/augusto-maillo) the [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical?version=nightly) was useful to fix *error*.

### Mulitclass classification

For **multi class classification** the **labels** have to be converted to a **matrix** use [`tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical) method for converting *labels* to a *matrix*.

### Syntax:

```
tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(
    y, num_classes=None, dtype='float32'
)
```

### Demo:

```
y = [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0] # we have 3 classes  0, 1 & 2

y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=3, dtype='int')

y

array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```